# Rails 3 - undefined method `delivery_handler='

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with delivery.

I get exactly this error:

```
NoMethodError in PagesController#send_message
undefined method `delivery_handler=' for #< Message:0x00000004db9648>

app/mailers/contact.rb:22:in `send_email'
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:65:in `send_message'
```

Anyway, here's my code:

*/views/pages/contact.html.erb*

```
<h1><%= @page.title %></h1>
<%= @page.content.html_safe %>

    <%= form_for @message, :url => "/pages/send_message" do |f| %>
    <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <% flash[:notice].full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <p><%= msg %></p>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Envoyer" %>
    <% end %>
```

*/models/message.rb*

```
     class Message
       include ActiveModel::Validations
       include ActiveModel::Conversion
       extend ActiveModel::Naming

       attr_accessor :email, :body

       validates :email,:body, :presence => true
       validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

       def initialize(attributes = {})
         attributes.each do |name, value|
           send("#{name}=", value)
         end
       end

       def persisted?
         false
       end
     end
```

*/controllers/pages_controller.rb*

```
    def send_message
      @message = Message.new(params[:message])

      if @message.valid?
        Contact.send_email(@message).deliver
        redirect_to request.referer, :notice => "Le message a &eacute;t&eacute; envoy&eacute;."
      else
        redirect_to request.referer, :notice => "Vous n'avez pas entrer votre email."
      end
    end
```

*/app/mailers/contact.rb*

```
      class Contact < ActionMailer::Base
        attr_accessor :email, :message

        default to: "bla@bla.com"
        default from: "blo@blo.com"

        def send_email(message)
          @message = message
          mail(:subject => "Nouveau contact blo")
        end
      end
```

*/config/environments/development.rb*

```
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
        host: 'localhost:3000'
    }
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
    config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
        location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
        arguments: "-i -t -f contact@test.com"
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your mailer, remove the `attr_accessor :message` or call it something else.

`ActionMailer::Base` already has a message accessor that gets/sets the `Mail::Message` being built, so bits of rails are calling `message` expecting to get a `Mail::Message` but is getting your Message class instead.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution in the night following my message. But, your answer is perfectly exact. Can't upvote since I have not enough reputation but I would do it if I could. Thank you very much.